# 2019 Moderator Election - why?

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

I know we haven't had a moderator election here in a while (6 years!), but why now? I don't get the impression that the current workload is too much for the current crop of moderators. Is someone stepping down? Or is the workload that much more?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Without going into too much detail - it's not my place to say who may or may not be stepping down - we (the mods) were contacted by the community team for the simple reason that it had been 6 years since the last election.

After a bit of discussion it was decided that, on balance, we did need an election.

Priorities change for people, real life intervenes and people don't have as much time as they used to to spend moderating. Also the prompt from the community team can be the catalyst for someone to say "you know what, I've had enough of this now". There's no ill-will or recriminations.